# show serials of dates in column based on two dates

Tags: excel, vba

i would  adjust  my code  when i fill data a3  and  b3  theses dates  it shows  serials of dates in column c  my code works  but  not  as what i would

```
    Sub test()
 Dim r As Range, x
 For Each r In Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 If IsDate(r) * IsDate(r(, 2)) Then
 x = DateDiff("d", r, r(, 2)) + 1
 With r(, 3)
 r.Copy .Cells
 .AutoFill .Resize(, x)
 End With
 End If
 Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `.AutoFill .Resize(x)`

Comment: yes this works  but i would not dynamic  in column a,b   how  can i  make  only a3 and b3

Comment: so you are going to possibly overwrite dates in column C?

Comment: it supposes  occurring  every time change filling  in a3,b3 automatically fill in column c as above image if is possible  by code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to:

- remove the `For Each` and `Next` statements, to avoid looping
- set `r` to the only range you want in column A

as follows

```
Sub testw()
    Dim r As Range, x As Long

    Set r = Range("A3")
    If IsDate(r) * IsDate(r(, 2)) Then
        x = DateDiff("d", r, r(, 2)) + 1
        With r(, 3)
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells) Then Range(.Cells, Cells(Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp)).ClearContents
            r.Copy .Cells
            If x > 1 Then .AutoFill .Resize(x)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: your adjusting works but not completely  when i  add a new date   it old date stay in column c  it supposes showing only based on what existed in a3,b3   and  clear the old  i  appreciate  to fixed this if you can do it as possible

Comment: See edited answer. If it solves your question, please mark it as accepted to direct future readers, too…

Comment: i have a simple detail  if   the a3=b3  it  works  but  gives me error  runtime 1004   highlight in this  line .AutoFill .Resize(x)  i try writting  this before  on error resume  next  to overcome this  problem   but  it doesn't  work

Comment: see edited code. `On Error Resume Next` is almost always a bad way out: it's like avoiding problems instead of facing them. Because they'll be after you right after

Comment: thanks  so  much i  would thank you  for your time  and your efforts  the code perfectly works

Answer (score 1):

In **C3** enter:

```
=SEQUENCE(B3+1-A3)+A3-1
```

and apply proper formats:

[image]

It automatically spills down to fill the date range correctly.  If you want VBA:

```
Sub dural()
    Range("C3") = "=SEQUENCE(B3+1-A3)+A3-1"
    Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Comment: i do this  copy  and  past for  your formula  or code  it gives me error c3 #name?

Comment: @ABDEL-FATTAHMAGHARI  It means that your version of Excel does not support the `SEQUENCE()` function.  **Ignore this answer**